# How to Log Complete HTTP Request

Tags: debugging, httprequest, header

I am trying to capture an HTTP request in it's entirety as it is sent from salesforce.

After adding headers my request I have attempted to use `JSON.serialize` and `String.valueOf`, where as `JSON.serialize` does not accept the HTTP Request data type and `String.valueOf` only returns the endpoint and method, not the header keys or their values.

I am able to iterate through the header values through the `.getHeader` method and provide the header to the method, but I would like to confirm no additional headers are being added and the headers are not being modified in anyway before being sent.

I would like to see exactly what the request looks like as it leaves Salesforce.

Comment: i have used a utility method to iterate through the headers and also use specific `getXXX` methods on `HttpRequest` object - returning the results in a string for logging

Comment: Yep, did the same with the utility on the response. I just have a client that refuses to check what they are sending back until I send them the request exactly as it is going out...